# loading file to java application

Tags: java, load, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

I am trying to load a file which I saved of a simple class. Below you can find my code which im using to load, the class which I need to cast is NewClientClass.

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            ObjectInputStream  in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile()));
            // = (NewClientClass) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            //IDNumber.setText();
        }
```

Below you can find the code which im using to save data.

```
 NewClientClass AddClient = new NewClientClass(IDNumber.getText(), FirstName.getText(), LastName.getText(), Address.getText(), DateOfBirth.getText(), Profession.getText());
       try {   
        int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile()));
            out.writeObject(AddClient);
            out.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Saved");
```

Can anyone help me with loading of the file of NewClientClass so I can show the details in textboxes after.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be almost there:

```
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            ObjectInputStream  in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile()));
            NewClientClass loadedObject = (NewClientClass) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            IDNumber.setText(loadedObject.getIDNumber());
            ...//Do the rest here.
            //IDNumber.setText();
        }
```